# BASH script regex: less than or equal to X digits

Tags: regex, bash

I want to match strings that have **less or equal to** 2 digits, but **not more than** 2 digits. If the digits are not consecutive, they could be more than 2 digits in total, but each consecutive digits should be at most 2 letters.

So, I want to match strings like

```
42
ABC92
05XYZ
ABC82XYZ
()%^.90 XYZ
AB 47.jpg
3
83abc29
9abw88ak ak8+
```

but not

```
426
ABC9242
05697XYZ
ABC8232XYZ
()%^.9068 XYZ
AB 479.jpg
483 a8
```

The letter before or after the digits can be not only alphabets, but also *any characters* that are not digit (No letters before or after the digits can be possible, and such strings should be matched, too).

`.*[[:digit:]]{1,2}.*` matches strings that have more than 2 digits, too. This is not what I want.

How can I do this?

Comment: what about `ABC2dsd2` should it match ?

Comment: @aelor sorry, it should be matched

Comment: @Naetmul Please clarify.  If it should match even if not consecutive, as in the case pointed out by aelor, shouldn't you remove the phrase "consecutive digits" from the question statement?

Comment: @John 1024 ok. I will make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using only `bash`.  Rather than trying to find anything with fewer than 3 digits, find whatever matches 3 digits or more and exclude it:

```
while read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" =~ [[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]] ]] || echo "$line"
done << EOF
42
ABC92
05XYZ
ABC82XYZ
()%^.90 XYZ
AB 47.jpg
426
ABC9242
05697XYZ
ABC8232XYZ
()%^.9068 XYZ
AB 479.jpg
EOF
```

Produces:

```
42
ABC92
05XYZ
ABC82XYZ
()%^.90 XYZ
AB 47.jpg
```

Explanation: The [binary operator `=~`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) considers the RHS as an extended regular expression.  It matches anything that contains 3 digits (or more).  The `||` is a short-circuit operator:

```
expression1 || expression2
```

which implies that `expression2` is executed only when `expresssion1` is false.

As such, only lines that do not contain 3 or more consecutive digits are printed.

---

You could also use `grep` using a flag to enable extended regular expressions or PCRE:

```
grep -vE '[0-9]{3,}' inputfile
```

or

```
grep -vP '[0-9]{3,}' inputfile
```

Comment: @aelor Edited the answer to explain.